# Can I create vapp without template with vcloud director api?

Tags: vcloud-director-rest-api

I cannot find method in vcloud director api that let me create empty vapp.

I wanna create vdc and vapp inside right away for that I can later create vms inside this vapp

Can I?

I cannot find api route for creating vapp without vms inside

Answer (score 0):

i found that method ComposeVApp solve my problem

https://developer.vmware.com/apis/1232/doc/operations/POST-ComposeVApp.html

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).